# Debian 9 Black Screen During Install

Tags: hp-proliant, debian-stretch

I have a HP Proliant DL380 G4 server which won't install Debian 9. I have tried various Debian 9 install images such as non-free, dvd, cd. I also tried writing the image to a dvd at 2x speed and 16x speed.

The problem is after getting into the Debian 9 Installer Boot Menu where I choose between graphical install and text install. It doesn't matter which I choose the server just shows me a black screen. I'm never able to actually proceed with the installation.

I tried booting using "noapic noacpi" once, "nomodeset" once then "vga=ask". When I used "vga=ask" I selected a lower resolution which finally gave me some output.

NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lookup - CPU#0 stuck for 23s
Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G    W

The images all came directly from debian.org. I believe the error above came from using the non-free installation image.

I'm not sure what to do from this point. I have never had problems installing Debian on these type of servers before. We have many G2 and G4 servers all running older versions of Debian. The firmware is up to date using the HP Firmware Maintenance CD and I get no other errors on the server itself.

Comment: Possibly need a combination of `acpi=off vga=ask` [debian bug 874251](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=874251) sounds a lot like what you're experiencing.

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek This solved the problem. Didn't think to combine the two.

Comment: This equipment is SO old... 13 years or so. Can you use more modern servers?